# Bundling with Webpack from external source gives "The target environment doesn't support dynamic import()"

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to create a simple bundle with a few JS from an external source, and a few JS files from the local source.

It fails when giving an external resource.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
        'https://unpkg.com/jquery-csv@1.0.21/src/jquery.csv.min.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
};
```

Error

```
Error: The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script
    at ExternalModule._getSourceData (/home/../development/widgets/node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModule.js:595:13)
```

It works when first downloading the external source's file contents, and pass it as local file.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
        // 'https://unpkg.com/jquery-csv@1.0.21/src/jquery.csv.min.js',
        './jquery.csv.min.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
};
```

- I don't know what `target enrivonment` is meant. My machine?
- `node_modules/webpack/lib/ExternalModule.js:595` Error was due to `runtimeTemplate.supportsDynamicImport()`. Can't I simply install a package which then silences the apparently missing `import()`?
- I am not doing any `import()` explicitly. The source code does not contain any `import()`
- I don't know what is meant with `external type 'module'` in the error

It has something to do with remote vs. local, since it's the same code in the entry.

The response of https://unpkg.com/jquery-csv@1.0.21/src/jquery.csv.min.js is without redirection `application/javascript;`.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/

Comment: I'm no webpack expert, not used it for a long while.  But -> `https://` is an external dependency, and webpack instead of bundling is maybe doing  `import('http...')`   Normally you would `npm install jquery-csv` instead of pointing at an external http resource.

Comment: Are you compiling to a target that supports dynamic imports? Do you have a browserlist config anywhere? Try `target: "es2020"`.

Comment: @morganney According to the docs it defaults to `web`. Sounds appropriate, but still opaque. I need the bundle to run on a web browser. I have no clue which target would support dynamic imports, the error could be more expressive.

Comment: @morganney With `target: "es2020"` I receive (also with local entry) `Error: For the selected environment is no default script chunk format available:
JSONP Array push can be chosen when 'document' or 'importScripts' is available.
CommonJs exports can be chosen when 'require' or node builtins are available.
Select an appropriate 'target' to allow selecting one by default, or specify the 'output.chunkFormat' directly.`

Comment: @Keith Seems like a working workaround. I will look into and see if it's my solution.

Comment: Ok, so looks like progress to me. With these things it’s really hard to debug from afar without a reproducible example. If you don’t have much experience with webpack then I would just install from npm if that is an option for you.

Comment: @morganney It should be reproducible with the first snippet, in an empty folder, with just the `webpack.config.js` file in it. Then running `webpack`. webpack-cli version is `^5.1.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is, first downloading the external source with npm.

package.json

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery-csv": "^1.0.21"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './entry.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'MyBundle.js',
    }
}
```

entry.js

```js
import csv from 'jquery-csv'; 
import MyWidget from './../MyWidget';

window.myWidget = new MyWidget(csv)
```